# Removing leading "../" from user supplied path

Tags: c++, string, replace, char

I have a simple C++ app that is used to execute perl scripts in a specific directory as another user.

```
wrapper my-perl-script.pl
```

I want to make sure that the user does not try to trick the C++ application into executing scripts outside the specific directory by prefixing "../". What is the best/simplest way to do this?

Here is a stripped down version of my wrapper source.

```
int  main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  /* set user here */

   stringstream userCmd;

   userCmd << "/path/to/scripts/";

   for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {

      if ( i == 1) {
         // remove instances of ../ from the first argument

         userCmd << argv[i]
      }
      else {
         // add user supplied arguments for perl script to command
         userCmd << " " << argv[i];
      }

   }

  /* use system to execute the user command */


   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What if they make a link?

Comment: What if they prepend a relative directory? What if they ask to run a file that's a symlink into wherever they like? What if the perl script they write goes off and does what it likes? There's a chance you're asking the wrong question here, so any clarification you can provide about specific details would be great.

Comment: @MarkB but what if Chuck Norris suddenly decides to trick the application by completely destroying it?

Comment: @CarlNorum: The user would need write access in /path/to/scripts in order to make the link in the first place.

Comment: @MarkB: I want to remove relative paths from the arguments they are supplying in order to prevent exactly what you describe. That is my question. How do I remove "../" from the string the user passes in, to prevent them using relative paths to run scripts outside this directory. I am the only one with write access to the directory and to the perl scripts.

Comment: While removing `../` leaves you with a name under the directory, it is probably better to reject the request rather than to modify it.

Comment: Very good point @JonathanLeffler. Thanks.

Comment: There's about a billion issues here. What if they pass in ./../ instead? What about /whatever/whatever? What if they add another folder to PATH and execute a script in that? Executing arbitary non-whitelisted apps from a privileged script is a very, *very* bad idea.

Comment: I guess the solution is to modify the permission of the directory. This will make sure that no scripts are executed outside the permitted directory. Dealing with relative-paths could be tricky.

Comment: @slugonamission as my question stated I want to get ride of "instances of ../". If they passed in "/whatever/whatever" they would end up executing "/path/to/scripts//whatever/whatever". If they added a folder to $PATH, they wouldn't execute a command in their path, because all the commands start with my hard coded "/path/to/scripts/". Regardless - I am following JonathanLeffler's advice, and terminating the script if the first argument begins with "." or "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer working with strings rather than raw pointers/arrays:

```
 int (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    std::string path (argv[1]);

    if (path.find("..") == std::string::npos)
    {
         //everything's fine
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No execution in parent directories allowed.";
}
```

The reason why you simply dont cut ".." is that the path wouldn't be correct anymore if the user entered something like "../bad/evenworse/script.sh"

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, the function `realpath()` will give you the absolute path of the file being requested which you could compare against the path to the base directory you want them to be able to access from. See here: [realpath manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realpath)

If the user were to provide `/path/to/scripts/../../../root/sensitive.sh`, `realpath()` would turn it into `/root/sensitive.sh` which you can compare against the allowed directory and throw an error to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't remove relative paths. If the user is trying to pass a relative path or full system path, then they are malicious - just terminate the application.

```
int  main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if ( argc == 1 || argv[1][0] == '.' || argv[1][0] == '/' ) {
     return 0;
  }

  ...
```

Thanks to Johnathon Leffler's comment for this solution.

Comment: What about `dir/../../../../dangerzone/`?

Comment: Good call. In my scenario {dir} as in, {/path/to/scripts/dir} does not exist. I have no sub directories under {path/to/scripts} - so the file system should give an error in the scenario you gave. You are correct though, there are safer solutions. Sceptical Jule also posted an answer that uses a string search for ".."